# Without null char in second argument for strcpy() function is returning unexpected result. Why?

Tags: string, strcpy, string.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[5];
    char b[2]="12";
    strcpy(a,b);
    printf("%s\n",a);
}
```

There is no null char in string **b** that is why the output is not as expected.
output : 12@
Why the output is coming like this only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

Your array `b` contains `{ '1', '2' }`. As you say, there is no null character in the array -- which means it doesn't contain a string.

`strcpy`'s second argument *must* be a pointer to a string. You gave it a `char*` value that is not a pointer to a string.

In practice, `strcpy` will probably continue copying characters from the memory following `b`. That memory contains arbitrary garbage -- and even the attempt to access it has undefined behavior.

In a sense, you're lucky that you got output that is visibly garbage.  If there had happened to be a null character immediately following your array in memory, and if your program didn't blow up trying to access it, it could have just printed `12`, and you might not have known that your program is buggy.

If you want to correct your program, you can change

```
char b[2] = "12";
```

to

```
char b[] = "12";
```

The compiler will figure out how big `b` needs to be to hold the string (including the required terminating null character).

Answer (score 1):

strcpy keeps copying until it hits a null character (byte with value 0x00). It copies whatever it encounters on the way.  In your case, memory after the array b happens to contain a byte with value 0x40 ('@') and then a byte with value 0x00.